# Making math operations in setText?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, settext, r.java-file

Why I'm getting error on this line ?

```
textView1.setText((editText1.getText() + editText2.getText() + (editText3.getText)) / 3);
```

Can we do math operations in `setText` method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
float result = (Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString()) +Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(editText3.getText().toString()))/ 3;
textView1.setText(""+result );
```

Comment: This is wrong. Your code will call `setText(int id)` and hence throws a `ResourceNotFoundException`.

Comment: Ok now that's fine, but your code will perform integer division.

Comment: ya you can convert into float or int as your vwish. but I think Result may be float value.

Comment: I would just point out that if you have `result = (5+5+6)/3;` result won't be equals to `5.33[...]` but to `5.0`

Comment: ya for that you have parse every string into float.

Comment: Or just divide by `3.0f`

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
textView1.setText((editText1.getText() + editText2.getText() + editText3.getText) / 3);
```

with

```
textView1.setText(""+(Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString()) + Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString()) + Integer.parseInt(editText3.getText().toString())) / 3);
```

Comment: No errors but app doesn't open on a device or emulator with this.

Answer (score 0):

`editText1.getText()` is returning a string. Adding the other getText's is performing string concatenation.

You need to convert the values to integer (or float) and then divide:

```
textView1.setText(String.valueOf((Integer.valueOf(editText1.getText()) + Integer.valueOf(editText2.getText()) + Integer.valueOf(editText3.getText)) / 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

`editText1.getText()` returns `Editable` which implements `CharSequence`. So you cannot directly perform arithmetic operations on such data types until you convert them into correct ones. For example: `int`, `double`...

Answer (score 0):

These methods will return String

```
editText1.getText()
editText2.getText() 
editText3.getText()
```

You need to cast to Integer or double.

eg `Integer.pargeInt(editText1.getText())`

for illustration try this one

```
String s="2";
System.out.println(s/3);
```

Comment: You forgot the semicolons :D :D